# Change table cell color based on a button selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, cells

I am trying to create a set of buttons that change the color of a clicked cell in a table.

for example:

1. User chooses the blue button
2. Only one button is allowed to be active at a time.
3. Any cell that the user clicks on changes blue (or red, green, yellow or white depending on the button selected.

The best I could do is the picture below. Please help or guide me to a solution. Thanks.

---

[image: table image]

Comment: Did you start the coding part, could you share your initial code

Comment: Hi Tariq - this basically very simple - I can explain how to do it. But at the moment I have to go out and meet some friends for a drink... If no-one else answers, then get back to me and I'll tell you.

Comment: So what you are actually say is that you want to get out for a drink while someone is going to do the homework for you? Sounds great!

Comment: some code ? Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample:

```js
var color = "White"

$( "#btnBlue" ).click(function() {
  color = "Blue"
});

$( "#btnGreen" ).click(function() {
  color = "Green"
});

$( "#btnYellow" ).click(function() {
  color = "Yellow"
});

$("table tr td").click(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input id='btnBlue' type='button' value='Blue' >
<input id='btnGreen' type='button' value='Green' >
<input id='btnYellow' type='button' value='Yellow' >

<br>
<br>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>col1</td>
  <td>col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>col3</td>
  <td>col4</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1242/

Comment: jquery not included.

Comment: click the link jsfiddle

Comment: i have verified, it is working. What is not working for you? Did you accessed https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1242/

Comment: What is not working for you? Any error? Choose your color by clicking on a button, then click a table cell, as per specified requirements. It is working just fine

Comment: dont run the snippet within the stackoverflow, click on the provided link

Comment: updated, so it is working within stackoverflow as well. You can run the snippet

Comment: Lucas you are miracle worker! This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks very much.

Comment: Stupid question. How do i mark the answer? I get a pop-up message saying that I can't if I have less than 15 reputation ponts.

Comment: gotcha, perhaps you cannot, not sure. I thought there is no point restriction for voting up. Oh well, nevertheless, glad I could help, till later, happy coding

Comment: One more thing please. How do i link the ".js" files to my html page? I cannot get it to work on my local pc. I'm using Visual Studio if that helps.

Comment: <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

Comment: I still can't get it to work :-(. below is my code 
<link href="p7p.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var color = "White"

$("#btnBlue").click(function () {
            color = "Blue"
        });

$("#btnGreen").click(function () {
            color = "Green"
        });

$("#btnYellow").click(function () {
            color = "Yellow"
        });
$("table tr td").click(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", color);
        });
    </script>

Comment: Here it is, copy and paste. Could not posted in comments, created new answer

Comment: <html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body><input id="btnBlue" type='button' value='Blue' ><input id='btnGreen' type='button' value='Green' ><input id='btnYellow' type='button' value='Yellow' ><br><br><table><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr><tr><td>col3</td><td>col4</td></tr></table>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">var color = "White";$("#btnBlue").click(function (){color = "Blue" });$("#btnBlue").hover(function (){color = "Blue" });$("#btnGreen").click(function (){color = "Green" });$("#btnYellow").click(function (){ color = "Yellow" });$("table tr td").click(function (){ $(this).css("background-color", color); });</script></body></html>

Comment: Hi Lucas... Is there anyway to get this done without jquery? I can't for the life of me get jquery to load with Visual Studio 2015. Does anyone know of another IDE that runs jquery? Please Help - Thanks.

Comment: I placed the full snippet in the last 2 comments. You dont need to worry about anything else, just copy paste,  I have used cdn jquery,so it should work just fine, assuming you have internet connection. In the answer above, you should be able to see a grayed out check mark bellow the downvote, could you check it to mark the answer

Comment: Still no luck. I have absolutely no Idea whats wrong. - I'm developing a program for users that i want to run through the "localhost". Have you tested this offline....If so could you please tell me how you were able to do it? Is there any chance that this could be done without using jquery? Thanks for your support and patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The code above will not work offline, you have to have internet connection. Dwonload jQuery yourself, and replace the cdn path that will point to local jQuery file, then it will work. Use code snippet in the previous two comments. Google how to link external jQuery file.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for helping. I clicked the check-mark above :-).

Comment: great, feel free to reach out in case of any further coding issues

Comment: Hi Lucas... I need help wrapping the script in a ready function like:                                                                                                      $( document ).ready(function() {
 
    // Your code here.
 
});

Comment: Here it is: <script>$('document').ready(function () {alert('x');});</script>

Comment: I'm referring to the code you wrote. I want to wrap your code into the ready function.                                                                                            var color = "White"

    $( "#btnBlue" ).click(function() {
  color = "Blue"
});

    $( "#btnGreen" ).click(function() {
  color = "Green"
});

    $( "#btnYellow" ).click(function() {
  color = "Yellow"
});

    $("table tr td").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });

Comment: right, just replace the alert with my corresponding js snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much... i am very new to this :-)

Comment: no worries, I've noticed, I've been there, keep coding, eventually you will get better, practice practice practice, no other way

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. Your code is working offline now. I wrapped it in the ready function, put it in the <body></body> area and referenced the jquery file I downloaded on my location machine.